# If $f(n)= n-2$ for $n>3000$ and $f(n)=f(f(n+5))$ for $n\leq 3000$,then find the value of $f(2022)$?

Tags: functions, contest-math

Let $f(n)=n-2$ for $n>3000$ and $f(n)=f(f(n+5))$ for $n\leq 3000$
I have to find $f(2022)$. I need to find out $\underbrace{f(f(f(f(..(f}_{197\text{ times}}
(3002)\cdots)$  because when $n>3000$ only then we can find the value,and I found out every recurrent four functions it comes out to be 3000 now finally it becomes $f(3000) =f(f(3005)=f(3003)=3001$
Is it the correct approach ?

Comment: This looks like a contest/olympiad book question. It would be nice if you could provide a source. Thanks.

Comment: It is one of the questions from CMI ug entrance exam 2022.

Comment: Can you edit that into the post above, @Oliva? It qualifies as a source. Also, this seems to (post-facto perhaps) involve contest-type methods, so I would like it if you could insert the [tag:contest-math] tag into the tags section. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand, we have a loop for recursive calling of our function. I calculated that every 3 steps we return to the same argument.
I have:
$$
f(2022) = f(f(2027)) = f(f(f(2032))) = f^{197}(3002) = f^{196}(3000) = f^{195}(3001) = f^{194}(2999) = f^{193}(3000) =\ ...
$$
As we can see, we've returned to the same argument, equal 3000.
Then we can divide 193 to 3 and get 64 full cycles and residue 1:
$$
f^{193}(3000) = f(3000) = f(f(3005)) = f(3003) = 3001.
$$

But i could make a mistake while calculating.

Comment: Your answer of 3001 agrees with my result from implementing the recursive function by computer.

Comment: So i can be sure that i was right.